# want to make my background image from attachments in CouchDB

Tags: jquery, css, couchdb, couchapp

i had on my _users document attachment image file
i want my background image change with each user
this code is not work with me

```
background-image: url(http://localhost:5984/_users/org.couchdb.user:test1/spaces_man.png);
```

and the console say  [HTTP/1.1 404 Object Not Found 10ms]

Comment: Does it work when you open http://localhost:5984/_users/org.couchdb.user:test1/spaces_man.png in your Browser?

Comment: no {"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}

Answer (score 0):

This strikes mo as extremely insecure. Unless you have no login requirement to access your database you can use this to access all the document is your db.

- Option 1:

Create an API that accesses just the image. Ideally you should check in the process that you are actually logged in, eg. you could pass some form of authorization to your API in order to return the image.

- Option 2:

Store all images on a separate file system and just store the URL in your user object, rather than manage it as an attachment.

Comment: i try option 2 but it need to create it with php and i search now to make couchdb and php work together  cus i dont know how i upload image just from couchdb and couchapp, about option1 i pass the admib user and pw and didnt work too

Answer (score 0):

what is the best API php/couchdb to upload image and if there are links for examples ,or the way to show my _attachment pic from my couchdb to html by this code 
`background-image: url(http://localhost:5984/_users/org.couchdb.user:test1/spaces_man.png);`